# Cannot save song from isolated storage, SaveSong method throws InvalidOperationException error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, invalidoperationexception, media-library

I'm building a FTP application for Windows Phone 8, and want to save the downloaded songs from the isolated storage to the media library. I check if the file exists in isostore, and it returns true, but when I'm using the SaveSong method it always throws an exception. Here is the code sample:

```
  private async void contextMenuItem1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext.ToString();
        MediaLibrary library = null;

        ......

        else if (fileName.EndsWith(".mp3") || fileName.EndsWith(".wav") || fileName.EndsWith(".aac"))
        {                
           IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

                if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
                {
                    library = new MediaLibrary();
                    StorageFile localFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

                    if (localFile != null)
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("StorageFile is: " + localFile.Name);
                        try
                        {
                            library.SaveSong(new Uri(localFile.Name, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), null, SaveSongOperation.CopyToLibrary);
                            //MediaLibraryExtensions.SaveSong(media, new Uri(fileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute), null, SaveSongOperation.CopyToLibrary);
                        }

                        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Exception caught: " + ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }

                else
                    MessageBox.Show("File does not exist in isostore");         
        }
    }
```

I wolud be very grateful if anybody could help me, thx.

Answer (score 0):

If your file name or file path is null then this exception comes.Also please verify `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_AUDIO` capability added or not.

[FYI](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/f5fa73da-176b-4aaa-8960-8f704236bda5/medialibrary-savesong-method?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: I have found the solution. It seems that the stream of the file was not closed, so I had these problems. Sometimes I could save the song, othertime I couldn't. After I close the file stream it seems to work without any problems

Comment: `IBuffer databuffer = dataReader.DetachBuffer();
                            RaiseFtpFileTransferProgressedEvent(databuffer.Length, false);
                            await ftpFileInfo.LocalFileStream.WriteAsync(databuffer.ToArray(), 0, Convert.ToInt32(databuffer.Length));
                        }
               await ftpFileInfo.LocalFileStream.FlushAsync();
                        ftpFileInfo.LocalFileStream.Close();
                        dataReader.Dispose();
                        dataReader = null;`